# Banning client from surfing the net

Tags: fortinet

In order to implement some egress traffic filtering so that a client can only visit specific web sites only, is it possible to configure a Fortinet FGT 60B to do some IP MAC address binding?

In a nutshell:

- A Fortinet FGT 60B works as a gateway
- A client `cl1` having a static IP should only be able to visit a specific web site

I also hope to prevent someone from plugging their network cable into a network jack and surfing the net.
In order to do this, I was thinking of doing some IP MAC address binding so that client `cl1` is monitored by the Fortinet.
Anyone having a different IP or MAC address should be banned from surfing the net

Is that feasible?

Comment: The accepted standard for physical port security is 802.1x authentication.

Comment: In such networks I personally make sure to change my MAC to an allowed one. Are you really sure you want to do this this? Think about secure solutions like RADIUS (802.1x) or blocking ports at the switch level (keywords: limit learning, mac-lockout)

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is surely possible. You can use two different approaches:

- **working at the IP level**: as your client has static IP, it is possible to define a rule that enable it to visit only specific websites and (eventual) DNS servers. Under that rule, create another one that deny all traffic to other destination. You can define source and destination addresses under "Firewall Objects"
- **working at the MAC level**: your Fortinet should be able to define a device by its IP address using the menu entry "User and device" -> "device" -> "device definition". You can then create custom rules based on that MAC address.

The first option is easier to administer (in the long run), but it is vulnerable to IP address change by a malicious user. To mitigate this problem, you can define a static ARP mapping between MAC->IP directly inside the Fortinet ARP table, but this complicate management.

If you select the second options, remember to enable "device-identification" on the interface where you define your MAC-based device. If can find some information [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yfJXTngBJKI) and [here](https://forum.fortinet.com/tm.aspx?m=118238)